# Set pop up location

Tags: swing, netbeans

I have a JFrame with a JTextArea: by clicking on this TextArea a JPopupMenu appears with two items "Clear" and "Save".

```
private void jTextArea1MousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
   jPopupMenu1.setVisible(true);
}
```

My question is: this popup always appears at position (0,0) but I would like to show pop where mouse is clicked, inside or relative to the TextArea.

I have try `setLocation(x,y)` but this methods always prompt in a fixed location and it is not what I am seeking for, and it is not available a method such as `setLocationRelativeTo(JTextArea());`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

don't use a mouseListener as trigger to show the popup, instead use the JComponent componentPopupMenu property, like

```
 myTextArea.setComponentPopupMenu(myPopupMenu)
```

Doing so will show the popup on right click at the mouse position by default. It has the additional benefit of covering keyboard triggered (LAF dependend, F10 on win) popup requests as well.

If for some reason you *really* need to manually show the popup, the method you're looking for is

```
myPopup.show(myTextArea, x, y)
```